# ¿Cuál es el error que comento aquí?

Tags: python, class

```py
reposo = 0

class Water():

    def encendido(self):
        if Water is True:
            print('El Water está funcionando')

        elif Water == reposo:
            print('El Water está en reposo')
        
        else:
            print('El Water está apagado')

print(Water)
```

Me dice: `<class '__main__.Water'>` sin nombrarme ningún tipo de error. ¿Estoy usando mal la clase?

Comment: Hay varios errores de logica en el código que muestras. Te recomiendo repasar Programación orientada a objetos e ir más despacio si es que así lo entiendes mejor.

Comment: Para empezar, 1- en la función encendido estás comparando la clase Water con booleanos y numeros. Como tu clase no es (ni deriva de) un boleano o un numero, esas condiciones siempre darán False. 2-En ningún momento llamas a la función encendido ni creas una instancia de la clase Water.

Comment: Lo que imprimes, es la forma que tiene Python de representar clases.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría conseguir que el código funcionase?

Comment: La verdad es que no se. Depende de cual sea tu objetivo. Cual es tu objetivo en ese print?

Comment: En realidad aca no hay ningun error, python esta haciendo lo que pedis...

Comment: Vale acabo de entender que me está imprimiendo la clase como tal, no fluyendo el programa. Gracias.

Comment: Que quieres que te imprima??

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque aquí no hay error alguno y la pregunta no describe un resultado esperado

Comment: Puede que quieras que se realice lo descrito en `Water.encendido`. Pero igual no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor explicación que vi sobre clases, objetos y métodos fue en los videos de **pildorasinformaticas.es**, te los recomiendo.

Te propongo un código por si se parece a lo que quieres.

```
class water:
    def __init__(self):
        self.encendido = False

    def abre_grifo(self):
        self.encendido = True

    def cierra_grifo(self):
        self.encendido = False

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Water está encendido' if self.encendido else 'Water está apagado'
```

Creas una clase y la inicias con el atributo `encendido`  a **False**. Despues creas métodos para modificar el estado del mismo.

Para poder imprimir el objeto puedes modificar el `__str__`.

**Lamadas a la clase:**

```
w = water()
print(w)
w.abre_grifo()
print(w)
w.cierra_grifo()
print(w)
```

Creas el objeto `w` y lo imprimes gracias al `__str__` .
Modificas el atributo del objeto e imprimes y observas como cambia el valor del atributo `encendido` .

**Los resultados son:**

```
Water está apagado
Water está encendido
Water está apagado
```